# Trying to output the richest user in my database through php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I know this is a bit of a rookie question but I'm trying to output the richest user's name on my website.
So my table is called **Users**
I have Column 1 ('**Name**') containing the names of all the users, and Column 2 ('**Bank**') containing their account balance.
I would like to find the richest user and output them on my website.
This is what I've got so far.

```
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldataGang, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $sqlgetGang = 'select name from gangs where bank = (select max(bank) from gangs) order by bank;';
    $sqldataGang = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlgetGang) or die('Connection could not be established');
    $welthiestGang = $row2['name'];
}
```

I know that there is a connection to the database as I have other statistics from other tables working... I have no idea why this isn't working... Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: No need for subqueries, just do a reverse order by `bank` and limit the number of records to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch a row from your `$sqldataGang` query object.

Add a line something like this to your program to [fetch the result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) right after your call to `mysqli_query()`

```
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldataGang, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

But, also, **beware**. A wise programmer always checks queries for errors. You can see how to do that [in the examples here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

Comment: And he shouldn't use mysql_query but mysqli_query. ;)

Comment: Ooops, @jonas3344, right you are. Error corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = 'SELECT name FROM gangs ORDER BY bank DESC LIMIT 1';
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT name,bank FROM Users order by bank desc limit 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

This will give you the richest person in your website

Comment: it will give you only one record and that will be the greatest

Comment: Not all the records, but just a single record with the highest money in bank.

Comment: @cdaiga The answer has been edited, the original did as jeroen said.

Comment: I know that but i can make my answer correct . the original answer was this $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT name,bank FROM Users order by bank desc";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); this will you the complete list of bank richer person from high to low